# Redirect to another page on button click --> Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am new to the below code and i got this from CodePen ,  the problem is am first to this and i want to redirect to another page on button click , since am not so familiar with javascript + jquery, i was not able to figure out how to . Can anyone help me with this

i tried giving URL as we do in AJAX but it was not , and i also gave window.location but in vain .

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let t1 = gsap.timeline({
  paused: true,
  reversed: true
});
let watch = false;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!watch) {
    t1.play();
    watch = true;
  } else {
    t1.reverse();
    watch = false;
  }
});

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "power1.out",
  rotate: 45,
});

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "power1.out",
  xPercent: -150,
});

t1.to(
  ".send", {
    x: -80,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1.5,
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  },
  0.2
);

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "elastic.in(2, 0.3)",
  x: 100,
  duration: 1.5,
});

t1.from(".done", {
  yPercent: -100,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1.2,
  ease: "bounce.out",
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EBECF0;
  transition: all 1.1s linear;
  color: #61677C;
}

i {
  color: #EBECF0;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0.4px #fff, 1.1px 1px 4px #BABECC;
}

button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 28px;
  color: #61677C;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px #FFF, 5px 5px 10px #BABECC;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px #fff, 2px 2px 5px #BABECC;
}

button svg {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  fill: #61677C;
}

button .done {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.0/gsap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>
      <span class="done">Done!</span>
      <span class="send">Send</span>
      <svg
        id="Capa_1"
        enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          d="m511.4 38.222c-1.109-20.338-17.284-36.511-37.622-37.621-41.038-2.242-121.342-.061-198.13 39.656-39.145 20.248-80.545 54.577-113.584 94.185-.407.488-.803.979-1.207 1.468l-74.98 5.792c-12.342.954-23.335 7.423-30.161 17.747l-51.154 77.372c-5.177 7.83-6 17.629-2.203 26.212 3.798 8.584 11.602 14.566 20.877 16.003l63.171 9.784c-.223 1.228-.447 2.455-.652 3.683-2.103 12.58 2.065 25.514 11.151 34.599l87.992 87.993c7.533 7.533 17.712 11.686 28.142 11.686 2.148 0 4.308-.177 6.458-.536 1.228-.205 2.455-.429 3.683-.652l9.784 63.172c1.437 9.275 7.419 17.08 16.001 20.877 3.571 1.58 7.35 2.36 11.112 2.36 5.283-.001 10.529-1.539 15.101-4.562l77.372-51.155c10.325-6.827 16.793-17.82 17.745-30.161l5.792-74.979c.489-.404.981-.8 1.469-1.207 39.609-33.039 73.939-74.439 94.186-113.585 39.719-76.791 41.896-157.096 39.657-198.131zm-175.394 393.037-74.011 48.933-9.536-61.565c31.28-9.197 62.223-23.927 91.702-43.66l-3.773 48.845c-.235 3.047-1.833 5.762-4.382 7.447zm-129.895-37.377-87.993-87.993c-2.245-2.246-3.283-5.401-2.774-8.44 2.616-15.643 6.681-30.534 11.713-44.562l132.028 132.028c-16.848 6.035-31.939 9.635-44.534 11.741-3.044.506-6.195-.529-8.44-2.774zm-117.923-222.269 48.844-3.773c-19.734 29.479-34.464 60.422-43.661 91.702l-61.564-9.535 48.934-74.012c1.686-2.55 4.401-4.147 7.447-4.382zm270.155 155.286c-24.233 20.213-47.756 34.833-69.438 45.412l-149.221-149.221c13.858-28.304 30.771-51.873 45.417-69.431 30.575-36.655 68.602-68.276 104.331-86.756 70.474-36.453 144.725-38.416 182.713-36.348 5.028.274 9.027 4.273 9.301 9.302 2.071 37.988.104 112.238-36.349 182.713-18.479 35.728-50.1 73.754-86.754 104.329z"
        />
        <path
          d="m350.721 236.243c19.202-.002 38.412-7.312 53.031-21.931 14.166-14.165 21.966-32.999 21.966-53.031s-7.801-38.866-21.966-53.031c-29.242-29.243-76.822-29.241-106.062 0-14.166 14.165-21.967 32.999-21.967 53.031s7.802 38.866 21.967 53.031c14.622 14.622 33.822 21.933 53.031 21.931zm-31.82-106.781c8.772-8.773 20.295-13.159 31.818-13.159 11.524 0 23.047 4.386 31.819 13.159 8.499 8.499 13.179 19.799 13.179 31.818s-4.68 23.32-13.179 31.819c-17.544 17.545-46.093 17.544-63.638 0-8.499-8.499-13.18-19.799-13.18-31.818s4.682-23.32 13.181-31.819z"
        />
        <path
          d="m15.301 421.938c3.839 0 7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l48.973-48.973c5.858-5.858 5.858-15.355 0-21.213-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.213 0l-48.972 48.973c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.928 2.929 6.767 4.394 10.606 4.394z"
        />
        <path
          d="m119.761 392.239c-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.213 0l-94.154 94.155c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.929 2.929 6.767 4.393 10.606 4.393s7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l94.154-94.154c5.859-5.858 5.859-15.355.001-21.213z"
        />
        <path
          d="m143.429 437.12-48.973 48.973c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.929 2.929 6.768 4.394 10.606 4.394s7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l48.973-48.973c5.858-5.858 5.858-15.355 0-21.213-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.212 0z"
        />
      </svg>
</button>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me please .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when you want the redirect, but you can use the [`.then()`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/then())

like `.then(function() { window.location = "https://google.com"});`

**Demo**

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let t1 = gsap.timeline({
  paused: true,
  reversed: true
});
let watch = false;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!watch) {
    t1.play().then(function() {
      window.location = "https://google.com"
    });;
    watch = true;
  } else {
    t1.reverse();
    watch = false;
  }
});

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "power1.out",
  rotate: 45,
});

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "power1.out",
  xPercent: -150,
});

t1.to(
  ".send", {
    x: -80,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1.5,
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  },
  0.2
);

t1.to("button svg", {
  ease: "elastic.in(2, 0.3)",
  x: 100,
  duration: 1.5,
});

t1.from(".done", {
  yPercent: -100,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1.2,
  ease: "bounce.out",
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EBECF0;
  transition: all 1.1s linear;
  color: #61677C;
}

i {
  color: #EBECF0;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0.4px #fff, 1.1px 1px 4px #BABECC;
}

button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 28px;
  color: #61677C;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px #FFF, 5px 5px 10px #BABECC;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px #fff, 2px 2px 5px #BABECC;
}

button svg {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  fill: #61677C;
}

button .done {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.0/gsap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>
      <span class="done">Done!</span>
      <span class="send">Send</span>
      <svg
        id="Capa_1"
        enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          d="m511.4 38.222c-1.109-20.338-17.284-36.511-37.622-37.621-41.038-2.242-121.342-.061-198.13 39.656-39.145 20.248-80.545 54.577-113.584 94.185-.407.488-.803.979-1.207 1.468l-74.98 5.792c-12.342.954-23.335 7.423-30.161 17.747l-51.154 77.372c-5.177 7.83-6 17.629-2.203 26.212 3.798 8.584 11.602 14.566 20.877 16.003l63.171 9.784c-.223 1.228-.447 2.455-.652 3.683-2.103 12.58 2.065 25.514 11.151 34.599l87.992 87.993c7.533 7.533 17.712 11.686 28.142 11.686 2.148 0 4.308-.177 6.458-.536 1.228-.205 2.455-.429 3.683-.652l9.784 63.172c1.437 9.275 7.419 17.08 16.001 20.877 3.571 1.58 7.35 2.36 11.112 2.36 5.283-.001 10.529-1.539 15.101-4.562l77.372-51.155c10.325-6.827 16.793-17.82 17.745-30.161l5.792-74.979c.489-.404.981-.8 1.469-1.207 39.609-33.039 73.939-74.439 94.186-113.585 39.719-76.791 41.896-157.096 39.657-198.131zm-175.394 393.037-74.011 48.933-9.536-61.565c31.28-9.197 62.223-23.927 91.702-43.66l-3.773 48.845c-.235 3.047-1.833 5.762-4.382 7.447zm-129.895-37.377-87.993-87.993c-2.245-2.246-3.283-5.401-2.774-8.44 2.616-15.643 6.681-30.534 11.713-44.562l132.028 132.028c-16.848 6.035-31.939 9.635-44.534 11.741-3.044.506-6.195-.529-8.44-2.774zm-117.923-222.269 48.844-3.773c-19.734 29.479-34.464 60.422-43.661 91.702l-61.564-9.535 48.934-74.012c1.686-2.55 4.401-4.147 7.447-4.382zm270.155 155.286c-24.233 20.213-47.756 34.833-69.438 45.412l-149.221-149.221c13.858-28.304 30.771-51.873 45.417-69.431 30.575-36.655 68.602-68.276 104.331-86.756 70.474-36.453 144.725-38.416 182.713-36.348 5.028.274 9.027 4.273 9.301 9.302 2.071 37.988.104 112.238-36.349 182.713-18.479 35.728-50.1 73.754-86.754 104.329z"
        />
        <path
          d="m350.721 236.243c19.202-.002 38.412-7.312 53.031-21.931 14.166-14.165 21.966-32.999 21.966-53.031s-7.801-38.866-21.966-53.031c-29.242-29.243-76.822-29.241-106.062 0-14.166 14.165-21.967 32.999-21.967 53.031s7.802 38.866 21.967 53.031c14.622 14.622 33.822 21.933 53.031 21.931zm-31.82-106.781c8.772-8.773 20.295-13.159 31.818-13.159 11.524 0 23.047 4.386 31.819 13.159 8.499 8.499 13.179 19.799 13.179 31.818s-4.68 23.32-13.179 31.819c-17.544 17.545-46.093 17.544-63.638 0-8.499-8.499-13.18-19.799-13.18-31.818s4.682-23.32 13.181-31.819z"
        />
        <path
          d="m15.301 421.938c3.839 0 7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l48.973-48.973c5.858-5.858 5.858-15.355 0-21.213-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.213 0l-48.972 48.973c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.928 2.929 6.767 4.394 10.606 4.394z"
        />
        <path
          d="m119.761 392.239c-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.213 0l-94.154 94.155c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.929 2.929 6.767 4.393 10.606 4.393s7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l94.154-94.154c5.859-5.858 5.859-15.355.001-21.213z"
        />
        <path
          d="m143.429 437.12-48.973 48.973c-5.858 5.858-5.858 15.355 0 21.213 2.929 2.929 6.768 4.394 10.606 4.394s7.678-1.464 10.606-4.394l48.973-48.973c5.858-5.858 5.858-15.355 0-21.213-5.857-5.858-15.355-5.858-21.212 0z"
        />
      </svg>
</button>
</body>
```